# C++ Exam Revision, Unsure why the correct answer is what it is

Tags: c++

So below is the question that we were asked and the code we were given to extrapolate from. Talking among my peers we can't seem to find the reason, any insight would be wonderful.

Why is the answer "min is 6 and max is 5" ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void minMax(double a, double b, double &min, double &max)
{
    if (a<b)
    {
        double min = a;
        double max = b;
    }
    else 
    {
        double min = b;
        double max = a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a = 5, b = 6, min = 6, max = 5;
    minMax(a, b, min, max);
    cout << " min is " << min << " and max is " << max;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friend...

Answer (score 3):

You are shadowing the parameters with local variable definitions, to fix write just a 100 times on your course log (and tell your peers of course):

```
void minMax(double a, double b, double &min, double &max)
{
    if (a<b)
    {
        /* double here defines a variable in local scope
           that shadows the reference parameter. */
        min = a;
        max = b;
    }
    else 
    {
        min = b;
        max = a;
    }
}
```